# To List All Rows Without Any Null Values

Tags: sql-server-2008, null

I have A table Named tblMaimtainsHdr,In that I have Columns as Given Below

```
Sl.no Asset_Id Building_ID MaintainsDate
1      0         1          21/02/2012
2      1         0          22/02/2012
3      2         0          23/02/2012
```

I want To select the asset_ID and maintainsDate where The asset_ID is Not Null

How To do it

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
select     Asset_Id,
           MaintainsDate
from       tblMaintainsHdr
where      Asset_Id is not null
```

assuming that `tblMaimtaimsHdr` (with an *m*)  was a typo :-)

---

And you should almost *always* have an `order by` clause on your selects. Not that it's pertinent to the question, just something I thought I'd mention :-)

---

If you want to get rows for everything where `Asset_Id` is neither `NULL` nor `0` (as per your comment), use:

```
select     Asset_Id,
           MaintainsDate
from       tblMaintainsHdr
where      Asset_Id is not null
and        Asset_Id <> 0
```

Comment: But the fields having '0' as itzz value is also getting selected..i dnt need Fields having '0' as their value

Comment: @Lijina: okay but, since that wasn't in your original spec, you'll have to raise a variation request, and I'll have to charge you extra :-) Sorry, I've spent the better part of the week putting together development contracts.

Comment: @Lijina why are you treating `NULL` and `0` as the same?